# Black screen on login on Ubuntu 22.04.01 with Nvidia drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 22.04, login-screen

So, I have fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 alongside Windows 10 (on separate drive). I have Nvidia GTX1050 GPU with Dell U2414H monitor via HDMI. Everything works fine, except for one small quirk. On boot, when it gets to login screen, my monitor instead goes black. Only messages I see on boot are

```
    [...] mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)
    [...] mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)
```

The weird thing is that I can easily fix that black screen by doing one of the following:

- Reconnect HDMI cable;
- Turn monitor on and off;
- Go to tty3 by ctrl+alt+F3 and then back to login screen by ctrl+alt+F1;
- With black screen, press enter, blindly enter password and press enter again.

All of that makes screen work fine. I am also experiencing this problem when logging out (getting black screen instead of login). I can see that monitor backlight is on, but for some reason monitor buttons (which open menu with settings like brightness and input source) do not work.

Looking at dmesg I see some nvidia errors:

```
[   51.343044] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   51.343149] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   51.343214] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   51.343278] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   51.388125] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   51.388243] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   51.388310] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   51.388376] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   51.419391] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
```

This problem happens only if using Nvidia drivers (I've tried purging and reinstalling multiple versions - 470, 510 and 515). With Nouveau it works fine. It also happens regardless of using Wayland or XOrg. It's not serious, but it bothers me to go through these motions every time on boot/logout.

Here's some info:

```
:~$ inxi -Gx --display
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050] vendor: Gigabyte driver: nvidia
    v: 515.65.01 bus-ID: 01:00.0
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.3 driver: X: loaded: nvidia
    unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,nouveau,vesa gpu: nvidia
    resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050/PCIe/SSE2
    v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 515.65.01 direct render: Yes
```

```
:~$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:37 memory:fd000000-fdffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-graphics
       product: EFI VGA
       physical id: 1
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       capabilities: fb
       configuration: depth=32 resolution=1024,768
```

```
:~$ nvidia-smi
Mon Sep 19 18:44:10 2022       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 515.65.01    Driver Version: 515.65.01    CUDA Version: 11.7     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 38%   36C    P0    N/A /  75W |    402MiB /  2048MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1086      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                123MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1292      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell              110MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2942      G   ...0/usr/lib/firefox/firefox      164MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Maybe someone had something like this? Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: It should work with recommended driver - given that you didn't change the kernel (driver and kernel are interconnected). The 470. drivers worked with my GTX1050 on Ubuntu 20.04...

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar problem, except that it was working fine for me until one day I got the black screen. The only thing that worked for me was downgrading my NVIDIA drivers to 510.

However, since I'm using CUDA, this broke the `nvidia-smi` tooling and also the `pynvml` Python package, so it's not a perfect solution. I'll try to maybe update it back later.

If you want to try doing it for your case, the step by step (I'm recalling from my head, so we might have a mistake in here):

1. In GRUB, choose Ubuntu (Advanced Options)
2. Pick an option with recovery mode.
3. Enable network
4. Start root shell
5. Find your nvidia driver version: `sudo apt list --installed | grep nvidia-driver`. Note which number it uses. In my case it was 515.
6. Uninstall nvidia drivers: `sudo apt-get remove nvidia-driver-515 nvidia-dkms-515`
7. Install a different version:

a) `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`

b) `sudo apt-get install nvidia-drivers-510 nvidia-dkms-510`

7. I had to set secure boot password again.
8. Reboot.

Hope that helps if you're stuck.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

- Press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> to enter a tty
- Login
- Type the following command

  ```
  cd /etc/gdm3
  sudo nano custom.config
  ```
- Uncomment this line

  ```
  Enable wayland=false
  ```
- save the file
- and reboot

  ```
  sudo systemctl reboot
  ```

This answer follows this link: [login-loop-ubuntu](https://support.system76.com/articles/login-loop-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I was seeing a blank screen after log in.

I was able to log in to the recovery mode properly, so the problem was definitely in the Nvidia drivers used in the normal mode as the recovery mode uses the Nouveau drivers.

So, upon restart, drop into the root shell prompt (either via the GRUB menu or CTRL+ALT+Fn) (Fn can be F1 to F6) and run:

```bash
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

The above command will autoinstall the drivers suited to your machine and update them.
Then, verify it using:

```bash
nvidia-smi
```

And, run:

```bash
sudo reboot
```

Now, you'll be able to log back in properly to your desktop with updated drivers.