# I'm having issues with booting up ubuntu

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gpu, gpu-driver, nvidia-geforce

Whenever I boot up my PC I get a black screen with beeping noise for around 5 minutes before getting onto the login screen... Then when I login I get another black screen with beeping for 2 minutes. I did not have this issue with manjaro or endeavouros. The issue occurred after installing Nvidia-515 Drivers.... Downgraded to Nvidia-510 Drivers... It's still doing the same thing.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Unfortunately there is nothing actionable in your question (unless you enjoy strangers on the internet guessing about causes and offering random solutions). Could you [edit] your question to include: (0) the version of Ubuntu you’re running (1) any errors contained in `/var/log/syslog` that might point to the issue (2) any other details that may point to a reason for this driver to cause your installation to break. With this, it may be possible to offer some specific advice 

Comment: 22.04 LTS when I run /var/log/syslog it says "bash: /var/log/syslog: Permission denied" I've tried running it with sudo but still no luck.

Comment: `/var/log/syslog` is a text file, not a program. You read it by using e.g. `less`, `tail`, `nano` or any other text tool.

Comment: nothing pops up

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a few hours ago. The new Nvidia driver (515) broke for my PC as well (RTX 3060 Ti, Ubuntu 22.04 LTS).
I fixed it as follows:

1. Reboot in recovery mode (from the grub)
2. Activate networking
3. Allow the disk to be written to (dpkg). I don't know if you can skip this step.
4. Enter a root session (root).
5. Execute:

> ubuntu-drivers devices

6. It should show you a list of drivers. Choose a previous one (nvidia-driver-510 works for me).
7. Install that driver manually:

> apt install nvidia-driver-510

8. Reboot (sudo reboot)

This should solve the problem. At least, it did for me. Good luck.

Edit: improved formatting.

Comment: sorry for the late reply I will try that I will update you on if it works when I do it :)

Comment: I clicked enable networking then clicked root and it just froze

Comment: I am sorry that didn't work. There is a similar thread here, maybe it will give you a hint:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1430188/black-screen-on-login-on-ubuntu-22-04-01-with-nvidia-drivers
I have also read something about booting without the UI, but you will have to get it working on your own, I am not very proficient with Ubuntu ^_^ I just encountered this annoying bug and wanted to help

Comment: cheers but still no luck I will be switching to openSUSE for the time being thanks for your help