# Black screen AFTER login on Ubuntu 23.04 with Nvidia graphics and command characters dropping from command when entered

Tags: command-line, drivers, nvidia, graphics, login

I may have more than one issue, so let me know if I need to create a separate question for one of these issues.

**

Update: June 25, 2023 I ended up re-installing Ubuntu 22.04. It took several attempts before I got a successful install. I had my previous home directory on the 2nd HDD, so I figure, since the new installation is only on the first drive, I would do the install, and then change the home directory to the 2nd drive. Consider this issue not resolved, but closed.

**

1st issue: Yesterday, some things start to bog down after an update which included the kernel. I typically keep up with updates as I am notified about them. After the update, I rebooted and everything booted up just fine. However, after login, I was faced with a black screen that I could run the cursor around on with the mouse, but nothing else.

Hardware: System 76 Bogo Extreme, 32 Gigs RAM, 420 SSD, 750 HDD, !TB Hdd. It is about 8 years old, but works great when there are no software issues.

I attempted to follow the instruction here. [Black screen on login on Ubuntu 22.04.01 with Nvidia drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1430188/black-screen-on-login-on-ubuntu-22-04-01-with-nvidia-drivers) to no avail. But the reason they were to no avail may be a 2nd issue.

First off, from the login screen, pressing Cntl+Alt+F2-9 doesn't do anything. I cannot get to the terminal that way. I was able to select the Ubuntu recovery screen on a reboot.

I am currently at the command prompt attempting to follow the instruction to set up a second user as a test to see if I get the black screen after logging in.

Issue 2. When I type a command, all of the characters are visible, but they are not all being passed to the OS when pressing "Enter".. The below is what I got each time I typed the command `adduser test`

`adduser test`

's: command not found'

`adduser test`

Command dduser not found, did you mean:

```
 command 'adduser' from deb adduser
 command 'dpuser' from deb dpuser
```

`adduser test`

ds: command not found

`adduser test`

Command 'addre' not found, did you mean:

```
 command 'addr6' from deb ipv6toolkit
```

Then I thought I would follow other instructions to go into etc to delete a config file. But the command character dropping persists with whatever command I type and the number of characters dropped is inconsistent.

`cd /etc`

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find ec: no such file or directory. At least the command CD was correctly recognized.

I had a graphics driver issue before that was resolved by downgrading the graphics card. However, I think I booted to a flash drive to run the commands from there. As usual, any help is very much appreciated.

UPDATE: The command prompt started working and I was able to add the new user Test. When the computer first boots up, the graphics work just fine while showing the login. Once I login with either my username or the Test username, all I have is a black screen that show the mouse pointer.

There are some things I noted from the bootlog that I transcribed here. Hopefully this will reveal something to someone.

May 04 19:20:59 Fort**** kernel: ACPI: OSL: Resource conflict; ACPI support missing from driver?

...

May 04 19:20:59Fort**** kernel: ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000563-0x000000000000054F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500 - 0x0000000000000563 (\GPIO_ (20221020/utaddress-204)

...

*kernel: nvidia: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.

*kernel: nvidia: module license ‘NVIDIA’ taints kernel.

*kernel: nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missiing - tainting kernel

...

*kernel: nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 238

*kernel: nvidia-modeset: Loading NVIDIA Kernel Mode Setting Driver for Unix platforms 470.182.03 Fri Feb 24 03:18:06 UTC 2023

*kernel: [drm] [nvidia-drm] [GPM ID 0x00000100] Loading Driver
last line in section:

The unit systemmd-fsckd.service has successfully entered the ‘dead’ state.

+++++++++++

[       0.064139] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-6.2.0-20-generic root=/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root ro nomodeset noresume

[       0.065188] Booted with nomodeset parameters. Only the system framebuffer will be available.

[       0.065200] Unknown kernel command line parameters “BOOT_IMAGE=vmlinuz-6.2.0-20-generic”, will be passed to user space.

**UPDATE 05.21.2023** I was able to get logged in on a terminal so I had access to the command prompt. I followed the instruction below to purge the nvidia drivers. I also upgraded the software in case it was a package that was causing the issue. I followed the instructions for installing the proper nvidia driver. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NvidiaDriversInstallation

After I rebooted, I was greeted with the message that said I was in "emergency mode" and gave several option, one of which was ctl+D to continue. I pressed control+D and ended at a black screen with a flashing underscore in the top left corner.

Now I am back to where I was before. When I am at the root prompt, I enter "exit" to continue booting into the default mode. It then hangs at "Starting default.target" After it hangs there for a while, it goes back into emergency mode. I am not so convince at this point that it is the graphics driver that is the issue. One more point. When I was logged in to the terminal as the regular user, everything in my home directory was gone except for one document that I type and save when testing to see if I could write to the drive after encrypting it.